# Which IIS role services are required for Sitecore?

Tags: iis, installation

I'm working on a new Sitecore 8.1 dev/uat/production infrastructure. We would like to reduce our possible attack surface and have a hardened installation from the start.

One of the Sitecore requirements is obviously IIS and the Web Server role! However I can't find any details about the features required for IIS. This either means that the defaults are necessary or perhaps it hasn't been deeply considered.

**Which role services are necessary for Sitecore to operate correctly?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't have a definitive list anywhere, and without actually attempting to remove each service one at a time until it breaks, here is the list of role services we use on a "locked down" Content Delivery environment (no Sitecore shell):

```
[X] Web Server (IIS)                                    Web-Server
    [X] Web Server                                      Web-WebServer
        [X] Common HTTP Features                        Web-Common-Http
            [X] Default Document                        Web-Default-Doc
            [ ] Directory Browsing                      Web-Dir-Browsing
            [X] HTTP Errors                             Web-Http-Errors
            [X] Static Content                          Web-Static-Content
            [X] HTTP Redirection                        Web-Http-Redirect
            [ ] WebDAV Publishing                       Web-DAV-Publishing
        [X] Health and Diagnostics                      Web-Health
            [X] HTTP Logging                            Web-Http-Logging
            [ ] Custom Logging                          Web-Custom-Logging
            [X] Logging Tools                           Web-Log-Libraries
            [ ] ODBC Logging                            Web-ODBC-Logging
            [X] Request Monitor                         Web-Request-Monitor
            [X] Tracing                                 Web-Http-Tracing
        [X] Performance                                 Web-Performance
            [X] Static Content Compression              Web-Stat-Compression
            [X] Dynamic Content Compression             Web-Dyn-Compression
        [X] Security                                    Web-Security
            [X] Request Filtering                       Web-Filtering
            [X] Basic Authentication                    Web-Basic-Auth
            [ ] Centralized SSL Certificate Support     Web-CertProvider
            [ ] Client Certificate Mapping Authentic... Web-Client-Auth
            [ ] Digest Authentication                   Web-Digest-Auth
            [ ] IIS Client Certificate Mapping Authe... Web-Cert-Auth
            [ ] IP and Domain Restrictions              Web-IP-Security
            [ ] URL Authorization                       Web-Url-Auth
            [ ] Windows Authentication                  Web-Windows-Auth
        [X] Application Development                     Web-App-Dev
            [ ] .NET Extensibility 3.5                  Web-Net-Ext
            [X] .NET Extensibility 4.5                  Web-Net-Ext45
            [X] Application Initialization              Web-AppInit
            [ ] ASP                                     Web-ASP
            [ ] ASP.NET 3.5                             Web-Asp-Net
            [X] ASP.NET 4.5                             Web-Asp-Net45
            [ ] CGI                                     Web-CGI
            [X] ISAPI Extensions                        Web-ISAPI-Ext
            [X] ISAPI Filters                           Web-ISAPI-Filter
            [X] Server Side Includes                    Web-Includes
            [X] WebSocket Protocol                      Web-WebSockets
    [ ] FTP Server                                      Web-Ftp-Server
        [ ] FTP Service                                 Web-Ftp-Service
        [ ] FTP Extensibility                           Web-Ftp-Ext
    [X] Management Tools                                Web-Mgmt-Tools
        [X] IIS Management Console                      Web-Mgmt-Console
        [ ] IIS 6 Management Compatibility              Web-Mgmt-Compat
            [ ] IIS 6 Metabase Compatibility            Web-Metabase
            [ ] IIS 6 Management Console                Web-Lgcy-Mgmt-Console
            [ ] IIS 6 Scripting Tools                   Web-Lgcy-Scripting
            [ ] IIS 6 WMI Compatibility                 Web-WMI
        [ ] IIS Management Scripts and Tools            Web-Scripting-Tools
        [ ] Management Service                          Web-Mgmt-Service
```

Obviously your requirements will vary depending on your setup.  If I had to guess at a minimum, I would go for the following:

```
[X] Web Server (IIS)                                    Web-Server
    [X] Web Server                                      Web-WebServer
        [X] Common HTTP Features                        Web-Common-Http
            [X] Default Document                        Web-Default-Doc
            [ ] Directory Browsing                      Web-Dir-Browsing
            [X] HTTP Errors                             Web-Http-Errors
            [X] Static Content                          Web-Static-Content
            [ ] HTTP Redirection                        Web-Http-Redirect
            [ ] WebDAV Publishing                       Web-DAV-Publishing
        [X] Health and Diagnostics                      Web-Health
            [X] HTTP Logging                            Web-Http-Logging
            [ ] Custom Logging                          Web-Custom-Logging
            [X] Logging Tools                           Web-Log-Libraries
            [ ] ODBC Logging                            Web-ODBC-Logging
            [ ] Request Monitor                         Web-Request-Monitor
            [ ] Tracing                                 Web-Http-Tracing
        [ ] Performance                                 Web-Performance
            [ ] Static Content Compression              Web-Stat-Compression
            [ ] Dynamic Content Compression             Web-Dyn-Compression
        [ ] Security                                    Web-Security
            [ ] Request Filtering                       Web-Filtering
            [ ] Basic Authentication                    Web-Basic-Auth
            [ ] Centralized SSL Certificate Support     Web-CertProvider
            [ ] Client Certificate Mapping Authentic... Web-Client-Auth
            [ ] Digest Authentication                   Web-Digest-Auth
            [ ] IIS Client Certificate Mapping Authe... Web-Cert-Auth
            [ ] IP and Domain Restrictions              Web-IP-Security
            [ ] URL Authorization                       Web-Url-Auth
            [ ] Windows Authentication                  Web-Windows-Auth
        [X] Application Development                     Web-App-Dev
            [ ] .NET Extensibility 3.5                  Web-Net-Ext
            [X] .NET Extensibility 4.5                  Web-Net-Ext45
            [ ] Application Initialization              Web-AppInit
            [ ] ASP                                     Web-ASP
            [ ] ASP.NET 3.5                             Web-Asp-Net
            [X] ASP.NET 4.5                             Web-Asp-Net45
            [ ] CGI                                     Web-CGI
            [ ] ISAPI Extensions                        Web-ISAPI-Ext
            [ ] ISAPI Filters                           Web-ISAPI-Filter
            [ ] Server Side Includes                    Web-Includes
            [ ] WebSocket Protocol                      Web-WebSockets
    [ ] FTP Server                                      Web-Ftp-Server
        [ ] FTP Service                                 Web-Ftp-Service
        [ ] FTP Extensibility                           Web-Ftp-Ext
    [X] Management Tools                                Web-Mgmt-Tools
        [X] IIS Management Console                      Web-Mgmt-Console
        [ ] IIS 6 Management Compatibility              Web-Mgmt-Compat
            [ ] IIS 6 Metabase Compatibility            Web-Metabase
            [ ] IIS 6 Management Console                Web-Lgcy-Mgmt-Console
            [ ] IIS 6 Scripting Tools                   Web-Lgcy-Scripting
            [ ] IIS 6 WMI Compatibility                 Web-WMI
        [ ] IIS Management Scripts and Tools            Web-Scripting-Tools
        [ ] Management Service                          Web-Mgmt-Service
```

PS. You can get/set these through the `Get-WindowsFeature` and `Add-WindowsFeature` PowerShell commands from an elevated prompt.